# SQL Math query doesnt gives good result with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have 2 tables.

```
 TABLE1
 ID_table1  EAN  type       REGION    CATEGORY FROM_DATE     TO_DATE  CONSUMPTION
    1      12312   A         WEST      11    2020-01-01  2020-02-02    13213
    2      12412   A         EAST      11    2020-01-01  9999-12-31    10000
    3      12327   A         EAST      21    2019-01-01  2022-01-01    2000
    4      12391   B         EAST      21    2020-01-01  2020-12-31    1000

 TABLE2
 ID_table2  DATE   HOUR   TYPE_B_COEFFICIENT TYPE_A_WEST_COEFFICIENT TYPE_A_EAST_COEFFICIENT cat_11_coe cat_21_coe

 1      2020-01-01  1       0.00521212          0.0123123           0.0202323                 1.23212    0.728290
 2      2020-01-01  2       0.00931212          0.0192323           0.0738292                 1.32012    0.929729
 3      2020-01-02  1       0.00529322          0.0023283           0.0329292                 1.99212    0.932111
```

And I need result

```
  EAN      DATE      HOUR     CONSUMPTION
12312   2020-01-01    1       200,444263207188
.......
```

Count is made like this = If EAN is TYPE A and region WEST and Category 11 is =
13213 *   0.0123123 * 1.23212 = 200,444263207188 and result is consumption for hour in day.

Output consumtion is calculated by multiplication of two coefficient from table2 and consumption from table1. There are many variables in calculated by type and region from table1. In the resulting view I need to show all EAN in TABLE 1 divided by day and hour with consumption for all hours

If i am using query without category coefficient all works good but with category coefficient gives bad result.

[Here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bu4fsMTFzgqTZeFubRmi14/0) is dbfiddle with working sql without category coefficient
And [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qzZqh77NuTJ9L91cUt2gtp/0)is bad count query with category coefficient
.

Comment: The fiddles run into an error ER_NO_SUCH_TABLE. You should also try to break it down to a minimal example, which can be posted here. Furthermore you should at least mention the expected result vs. the erroneous result in the question. But as your coeffictients are quite small and you are suming up a lot of values, I suppose the problem might be the precision of the floating point operations.

Comment: updated dbfiddle..
query works well if I have another table with another coeficient without cat_coe. But If i add into query cat_coe gives bad result

Comment: So again, what is the expected result, what are the current results? What do you mean by *good* result and *bad* result. Describe what you are doing in your query and create a MINIMAL example which shows the problem. (Nobody wants to analyse 200 LOC of SQL) My guess is (without much further analysis) that you have a precision problem. Your coefficients have 20 decimal places of precision. But if you multiply two numbers each with 20 places after the decimal point, you would need 40 places to hold the exact value. And if you sum up all those inaccurate values, you get even more inaccuracy ...

Comment: Ok so another way.. is query (bad query) good writed ? Can I use this: Ok so another way.. is query (bad query) good writed ? Can I use this:           WHEN t1.aktualizace_ciselniku_tdd = 'A' 
         AND region = 'WEST' AND category = '11' THEN t2.TYPE_A_WEST_COEFFICIENT* t1.CONSUMPTION* t2.cat_11_coe 
in command ? In use with multiple regions and category ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
select t1.ean, t2.date, t2.hour,
       (t1.consumption *
        (case when type = 'B' then type_b_coefficient
              when type = 'A' and region = 'EAST' then type_a_east_coefficient
              when type = 'A' and region = 'WEST' then type_a_west_coefficient
              else 1
         end) *
        (case when category = 11 then cat_11_coefficient
              when category = 21 then cat_21_coefficient
              else 1
         end)
       ) as net_consumption
from table1 t1 join
     table2 t2
     on t2.date = t1.from_date
```

Comment: Yes, but this query doesnt count good.. Result is 41 in my table with consumption but good result is about 4300 and query get only 200 rows but with my query I gets about 16000 rows.
[This](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/siu1HsBzcdyfLtqwZ9qzRr/0) query works good without consumption multiply by cat_11_coefficient, cat_21_coefficient etc.. Is there any way for modify this query from db-fiddle for cat_coefficient add ?

Comment: @MilanLidmila . . . I don't understand your queries at all.  This answers the question that you have asked.

Comment: @MilanLidmila - What count are you referring to?